# Unable to Start Stanford CoreNLP server with Shift-Reduce Parser

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have setup coreNLP server on local and can be started using command:

```
java -mx5g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer  -timeout 100000
```

But default constituency parser is set with following warning message:

> warning: cannot find edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz
>
> using: edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz instead

I downloaded the shift reduce parser, extracted jar file and pasted **edu** folder in project directory.

To double check, I manually traversed to edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser to make sure **englishSR.ser.gz** exists.

Also, created **.properties** file and used -serverProperties option when starting server again.

**StanfordCoreNLP.properties** file contains:

```
parser.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz
```

- Command to run server is now:

> ```
> java -mx5g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -timeout 100000 -serverProperties "StanfordCoreNLP.properties"
> ```

No luck and I am still getting the same warning.
Please comment if more clarification is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the full English models jar in the directory where you are running this command.

The `-cp "*"` is saying to look at all jars in that directory.

You can find that English models jar here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html